# How to define belongsTo and hasMany Relationship in Sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize.js as ORM, and I'm trying to define the relationship between two objects: Review and User. One User can write/have many reviews. Therewith, one review always belongs to exactly one user. There is no join table, this information is saved in the Review object in a column called user_id.

I tried to define the relationship as follows:

```
Review.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
User.hasMany(Review, { foreignKey: 'user_id', useJunctionTable: false });
```

Now I'm using a find on Review and I want to include the user object. I do so using:

```
Review.find({
    where: {
        id: reviewId
    },
    include: [User]
});
```

I retrieve the error

> ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'user.user_id' in 'field list'.

Sequelize asks for `user`.`user_id`, since it somehow thinks it should do this. The really interesting thing is that it worked somehow but now doesn't work anymore. The documentation is not so talkative here as it should be, so I'm not sure how to define the association between both objects, or the `belongsTo` relationship in general. Maybe anyone of you can help me out here.

Comment: What version are you testing on? I just tried this with the latest master (v1.7.0-beta.1, and it seems to work fine

Comment: I'm using the 2.0beta1 version. I now completely redesigned the associations between all associations, and it finally works! Really error-prone :-)

Comment: I know that this question is quite old by now but I have exactly the same problem. What did you take into account when redesigning the associations? Is there something that you did misunderstand and I do misunderstand? ;)

Comment: Except for the useJunctionTable I still use the same association definition, and it still works (now using Sequelize 3.x)

Comment: I'm running into 3 almost 3 years later. Any one know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Model: `User.js`

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const user = sequelize.define("User", {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
    }, {
    });

    user.associate = function (model) {
    }

    return user;
};
```

Model: `Review.js`

```
"use strict";

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Review = sequelize.define("Review", {
        user_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
        detail: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    }, {

    })
    Review.associate = function (model) {
        Review.belongsTo(model.User, {
            as: 'user',
            foreignKey: 'user_id'
        });
    }
    return Review;
};
```

Controller.js

```
var r = await db.Review.findOne({
    where: {},
    include: ['user']
});
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r)))
```

**Output**

```
{
  id: 1,
  user_id: 1,
  detail: 'Test Review',
  createdAt: '2021-03-09T16:43:09.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-03-09T16:43:09.000Z',
  user: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test User',
    createdAt: '2021-03-09T16:43:09.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-03-09T16:43:09.000Z'
  }
}
```

```
"sequelize": "^6.5.0", 
"mysql2": "^2.2.5",

Tested in Win10, mysql
```

https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize : `stack-19840471` branch